# Structure to hold a set of ranges merging intersecting ranges

Tags: data-structures

Hoping to see if anyone is familiar with a known data structure that would perform as follows.

I want to store a set of ranges (ex [1,3], [7,9]) but on insertion the data store would result in the "compressed" version, ie: given the data structure has nodes [2,4] and [5,6] and insertion of [4, 6] would result in a data store that results in one node of [1, 9].

I'm in the process of building a tree to do this, hoping someone may be able to point me to the right "googly" words.

Motivation: Let's say I have a sequence of IDs I expect in a message protocol. I want to be able to store which ones have been received. Let's say the IDs are 64bits, and we can have 64bits worth of IDs. 2^128 seems like a lot of storage to store this information.

So if instead I can store ranges, gaps in sequence IDs should be sparse therefore my idea is to have [n, m] describe that the sequence ids from n to m have been received. I'm open to ideas.

This is where I'm at right now, far from being complete, it is still a working concept. I would ignore this for the most part.

```cpp
struct Range
{
    explicit Range(std::int64_t range1)
        : lower(range1), upper(range1)
    {
    }

    void merge(Range& rhs)
    {
        lower = std::min(rhs.lower, lower);
        upper = std::max(rhs.upper, upper);
    }

    bool operator<(Range& rhs)
    {
        return upper < rhs.lower;
    }

    bool operator=(Range& rhs)
    {
        return lower == rhs.lower && upper == rhs.upper;
    }

    bool intersect(Range& rhs)
    {
        return (lower >= rhs.lower && lower <= rhs.upper) || (upper <= rhs.upper && upper >= rhs.lower);
    }

    std::int64_t lower, upper;
};

bool rangeWithinOne(const Range& lhs, const Range& rhs) 
{
    if (abs(rhs.lower - lhs.lower) <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (abs(rhs.upper - lhs.upper) <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

struct RangeTreeNode
{
        RangeTreeNode(const Range& r)
            : right(NULL), left(NULL), range(r)
        {
        }

        const Range& getRange()
        {
            return range;
        }
    private:
        friend class RangeTree;
        RangeTreeNode* right;
        RangeTreeNode* left;
        Range range;
};

class RangeTree
{
public:
    void insert(const Range& r)
    {
        Range tmp = r;
        tmp.lower -= 1;
        tmp.upper += 1;

        std::pair<RangeTreeNode*, bool> insertion = findIntersection(tmp);
        if (insertion.second)
        {
            insertion.first->merge(r);
            // need to merge the sub trees though!!!!
        }
    }

    template<typename Visitor>
    void visitAll(const Visitor& v) 
    {
        visitAllHelper<Visitor>(v, mHead)    
    }


private:
    template<typename Visitor>
    void visitAllHelper(const Visitor& v, RangeTreeNode * const node)
    {
        if (node == NULL)
            return;

        v.visit(node.range);
        visitAllHelper(v, node->right);
        visitAllHelper(v, node->left);
    }

    std::pair<RangeTreeNode*, bool> findIntersection(const Range& r) const
    {
        RangeTreeNode* iter = mHead;
        RangeTreeNode* parent;
        while (iter != NULL)
        {
            if (iter->range.intersect(r))
            {
                return std::make_pair(iter, true);
            }

            parent = iter;
            if (r < *iter)
            {
                iter = iter->left;
            }
            else
            {
                iter = iter->right;
            }
        }

        return std::make_pair(parent, false);
    }

    RangeTreeNode* mHead;
};
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: interval_tree sounds like some good googling words, going to look into this, but the wiki page linked doesn't lead me to any specifics on how to handle an interval tree that will reduce itself on insertion

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using C++, the easiest way to do this is to put the ranges into an `std::set` or `std::map` (if they have associated values) sorted by their end positions.

Then, to insert `[s,e]`, you can use `lower_bound([s-1,s-1])` to get the first existing range that might overlap or abut the new one, walk forward to find all mergeable ranges, and replace them with a single range.

Something like this:

```
void insert(int newStart, int newEnd) {
    set<Range>::iterator it;
    if (newStart > INT_MIN) {
        it = theset.lower_bound(Range(newStart-1, newStart-1));
    } else {
        it = theset.begin();
    }
    while( it != theset.end() && (newEnd == INT_MAX || it->start <= newEnd+1)) {
        newStart = min(it->start, newStart);
        newEnd = max(int->end, newEnd);
        theset.erase(it++);
    }
    theset.insert(Range(newStart,newEnd));
}
```

That way you will have only disjoint ranges in the set/map, which I believe is what you want, and insert takes amortized O(log N) time.

Comment: I'm trying to work this one out, I originally thought about using set, but it just seemed like more work to get it correct, and then I'd still need to wrap the logic in some interface, and my initial intuition assumed that any removal from set, through the set interface would be a lot more expensive then something I could do in a specialized container

Comment: It's pretty efficient, and *way* easier that writing your own tree.  I added some insert code ^^

Comment: I up voted, this does indeed work but insertion is O(nlogn) worst case, I think a specialized structure could do better, still haven't found something describing what I want. Maybe I'm thinking about it to specifically trying to find the data structure, and need to expand out to thinking about in terms of what I'm trying to solve as far as holding the sequence IDS, which wasn't originally detailed.

Comment: O(n log n) worst case, but O(log n) *amortized*, since each O(log n) of extra work deletes an item what was previously added, for which O(log n) of insertion work was already spent.